# What is the testng equivalent of junits @ClassRule

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng

Junit has a decorator called @ClassRule that is applied around the test class. I am trying to find the same thing in testng without any success this far. What would be the best way to do a @ClassRule in testng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no direct testng equivalent, but it's generally easy to do the same thing using the `@AfterXXX/@BeforeXXX` annotations.  In your case, you could use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations on 2 different methods to emulate the same thing

You can find more information on the supported annotations on the 
[testng website](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations)

Comment: Not an option at the moment. We are using a @ClassRule from dropwizard. I guess I could do the approximately same thing in a Before/After combo though. Thanks for verifying my suspicion!