# How to implement in testng junits @ClassRule using AfterXXX and BeforeXXX

Tags: java, junit, testng

As I googled, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053886/what-is-the-testng-equivalent-of-junits-classrule) question have accepted answer saying, that there is a way to implement the @ClassRule by using AfterXXX and BeforeXXX methods.

How to implement @ClassRule using those methods?

Comment: And what does @ClassRule do anyway? TestNG is much more powerful than JUnit in general, but they work quite differently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit:

```
public class UsesExternalResource {
  public static Server myServer= new Server();

  @ClassRule
  public static ExternalResource resource= new ExternalResource() {
    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
      myServer.connect();
    };

    @Override
    protected void after() {
      myServer.disconnect();
    };
  };
}
```

TestNG:

```
public class UsesExternalResource {
  public Server myServer= new Server();

  @BeforeClass
  public void before() {
    myServer.connect();
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void before() {
    myServer.disconnect();
  }
}
```